# Java Concurrent Recursive API Access

Tags: java, multithreading, api, thread-safety, concurrency

I don't get to write multithreaded applications very often, so be gentle with my threads :-)

I have an API input which contains a "score" and then a bunch of child nodes which also have scores, and perhaps child nodes of their own. I need to quickly sum up the total score of the entire tree.

I've elected a newWorkStealingPool as I have read that this is a good implementation for applications where workers may spawn other workers.

My handler is awfully static. I don't always work in Java, but this felt like the appropriate solution. Correct if wrong? :-)

I *think* I've made thread safe the methods that could be troublesome. I'd obviously like to remove the synchronization from methods that maybe don't need it.

I'm **very** concerned about how I monitor the running threads to decide when my work is done. I think there is a race condition here that I am having trouble understanding, even if for now, this project works.

Don't worry too much about my throwing an Exception, please :-). It's just for now so as to not clutter up the other code.

Thank you!!

Oh! Java 8 is pretty new to me, too. I only just considered where I could use some new functionality.

Runner

```
import java.net.URL;

public class Runner {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        try{
            NodeHandler.addNode(new Node(new URL(args[0])));
        }catch(java.net.MalformedURLException e){
            System.out.println("Malformed URL Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        System.out.println(Double.toString(NodeHandler.getTotal()));
    }

}
```

Node Handler

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class NodeHandler {
    private static int runningThreads = 0;
    private static double rewardsTotal = 0;
    private static ExecutorService es = Executors.newWorkStealingPool();

    public static synchronized void addNode(Node node) {
        es.execute(node);
    }

    public static synchronized void incrementThreadCount() {
        runningThreads++;
    }

    public static synchronized void decrementThreadCount() {
        runningThreads--;
    }

    public static synchronized void updateScore(double score){
        scoreTotal += score;
    }

    public static int getRunningThreads() {
        return runningThreads;
    }

    public static double getTotal(){
        while(getRunningThreads() > 0){
            try {
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return scoreTotal;
    }

}
```

Node

```
import java.util.*;
import java.net.URL;

import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;

public class Node implements Runnable{

    private URL url;
    private StringBuilder rawJson = new StringBuilder();

    Node(URL url){
        NodeHandler.incrementThreadCount();
        this.url = url;
    }

    private void processNode() throws Exception{
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(url.openStream());

        while (sc.hasNext()) {
            rawJson.append(sc.nextLine());
        }
        sc.close();

        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
        JSONObject jObj = (JSONObject) jParser.parse(rawJson.toString());
        JSONArray children = (JSONArray) jObj.get("children");
        NodeHandler.updateScore(Double.parseDouble(jObj.get("score").toString()));

        if (children != null && children.size() > 0) {
            for (Object o : children) {
                URL url = new URL(o.toString());
                NodeHandler.addNode(new Node(url));
            }
        }
        NodeHandler.decrementThreadCount();
    }
    @Override
    public void run(){
        try {
            processNode();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A few things that I noticed, not necessarily in order:

- The globally locked and secured `total` is an unnecessary bottleneck. The aggregation you're performing is really well-suited for subresult aggregation. Instead of `updateScore` which can only ever be entered by one thread, you should have a running aggregate as you traverse the node hierarchy.
- Node should not know about `NodeHandler`. You're tightly coupling these two together through a static method, which makes your code hard to test. Instead of a static class, use dependency-injection
- Your termination condition isn't perfectly secure against premature termination. Also the `getTotal` is basically busy-waiting. You also only ever have multiples of seconds when running this task, which doesn't bode well for smaller node-structures.
- Declaring `rawJson` as a member-variable is not a good solution. The compiler may or may not notice that it's in fact a local variable and may or may not correctly free the memory you're not using anymore.
- Java EE has a [JsonParser](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/json/stream/JsonParser.html) implementation since Java 1. That implementation crucially allows directly streaming the JSON access, so long as you're using forward access only. This allows you to keep a minimal memory-footprint. Look into [`Json.createParser(InputStream)`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/json/Json.html#createParser-java.io.InputStream-)
- Since you're creating tasks from your initial task, the [`ForkJoinPool`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html) and the use of [`ForkJoinTask`s](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinTask.html#invoke()) is the "correct" model to use here. With this knowledge we can rewrite your program to be significantly more idiomatic and probably quite a bit faster :) This also allows you to not need to think about the termination condition of your operation.

Comment: do note that because of floating point errors, depending on the order of calculation you may get different results

Comment: This is all great stuff! I wanted to ask for clarification on your initial point about the running aggregate. Would this be like an aggregation thread holding a collection of our scores which we concurrently update as we traverse the nodes? Then when all tasks are finished we can sum the stored scores?  And on your last point: It looks like the newWorkStealingPool is backed by a ForkJoinPool. In fact, it's just an abstraction over it. I guess I'm missing what I should change about the implementation on the threadpool here.

Comment: @charstar re 1: I was suggesting to have a "total" inside a Node, which incorporates the total from all it's children + it's own score. That way you don't even need global state and the static total disappears. That even allows you to calculate two of these tree-structures in parallel. The threadpool itself is ... okay. It's a good solution for the abstraction of a Node being a thread. If your node was a `ForkJoinTask`  instead (or even more idiomatic a `RecursiveTask`), that abstraction falls apart. You won't even need an explicitly declared ForkJoinThreadPool then